# LinearLayout XML error

Tags: android, xml

Hi I'm doing a mapOverLay tutorial online, and I'm getting an error in  my xml. At the LinearLayout tag I'm getting the error "unexpected namespace prefix xmlns found for tag LinearLayout" I tried removing it, but that didn't work. Any Ideas what the problem might be??

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <view android:id="@+id/mv"
            class="com.google.android.maps.MapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:clickable="true"
            android:apiKey="07WVUg-srWUY6iEC2qTEiuT1mKYkoo6EVPK74pA"
            />

            <!-- Must replace apiKey above with appropriate one for your development machine  -->

         <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:padding="0px"           
            >

        <Button android:id="@+id/doOverlay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" 
            android:textSize="12sp"   
            android:text="@string/overlay_label" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/doAccess"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:textSize="12sp" 
            android:text="@string/access_label" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/doRoute"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="30px"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:textSize="12sp" 
            android:text="@string/route_label" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: use the namespace attribute only in the root tag so remove the "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" attribute from the LinearLayout.. it may work that way

Comment: you're welcome :).. just accept as answer Pragnani's answer.. it's the same thing as I said and it may help others too..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:padding="0px"           
                >
```

Remove `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`